# How to enable preview thumbnail on tracker - ie screenshot at timecode - on embedded vimeo video?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-player

Is it possible to enable the preview thumbnails (that you see when hovering over the tracker bar) on an embedded Vimeo video?

[image]

These are visible on my videos when viewed on vimeo.com. However, on the embedded video, all we see is the timecode, no tooltip with a screenshot.

I've checked the API docs and looked for settings in the video config and embedded presets - I cannot see any parameter to enable/disable this feature - am I missing something?

*(Background: I have a Vimeo Pro account and am using ReactPlayer to dynamically render videos.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thumbnail preview in the playbar is only available when viewing the video on vimeo.com. It is not yet possible to show thumbnail previews on embedded videos.

Comment: Ok - I hope this functionality becomes available in future. If anyone is aware of a vimeo feature request for this, please share the link, I would love to add a +1 to it.  Thank you :)